# Adding alphabetic sorting chars to an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Basically I have an array of customer names already sorted:

```
Al K. Seltzer
Alf A. Romeo
Ali Gaither, Ali Katt
Amber Green
Cam Payne
Cara Van
Craven Moorehead
Crystal Ball
Crystal Claire Waters
Ford Parker
Forrest Green
Foster Child
```

And I want to add sorting chars:

```
**A**
Al K. Seltzer
Alf A. Romeo
Ali Gaither, Ali Katt
Amber Green
**C**
Cam Payne
Cara Van
Craven Moorehead
Crystal Ball
Crystal Claire Waters
**F**
Ford Parker
Forrest Green
Foster Child
```

My current approch:

```
function addSortigChars(elements) {
  var lastChar=elements[0].LastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
  var newArray=[];
  newArray.push(lastChar);
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
      var newChar=elements[i].LastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
      if(newChar!=lastChar) {
         lastChar=newChar;
         newArray.push(lastChar);
      }
      newArray.push(elements[i]);
  }
  return(newArray);
 }
```

I think to loop over every element is  very inefficient. Is there any efficient way to do this?

I'm using knockout to bind to the DOM. Is there any buildin-function in ko that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that lopping over every element is not the most efficient solution, but i would argue that the performance benefit from optimizing it is not worth the added complexity.

Still, if you really want to optimize it, you could! You could start off by setting an estimate on the number of entries for each letter, so for example if you have 1000 elements, you could estimate that the names starting with A will be around 100.
Then you can use a version of binary search to find the first name starting with B, in the range 0, 200. Keep in mind that 200 is a soft-limit, if your estimate is really bad and all the names between 100 and 200 start with A, you need to consider going past it. In fact, i would use the maximum as (estimate + max known A) and update it when a bigger A is found.
Once you do that to find the first B === the place where you have to insert **B**, then you move on to the next letter.

By using (modified) binary search, you are guaranteed to skip over most elements. The efficiency is in part determined by the accuracy of your estimate.

Good luck with the implementation!

---

A cleaner implementation of your original algorithm which changes the array in place:

```
function addSortingChars(elements) {
  var last = '';
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i][0].toUpperCase() !== last) {
      last = elements[i][0].toUpperCase();
      elements.splice(i, 0, last);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate your array backwards! [demo](http://jsbin.com/fopubebu/1/edit)

```
var mem = arr[arr.length-1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase(); // memorize: "F"    
for(var i=arr.length-1; i>-1; --i){
  var fc = arr[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();           // first character
  if(mem!=fc || !i){
    arr.splice(!i?0:i+1, 0, "***"+mem+"***");
    mem = fc;
  }
}
```

if you log your `arr`:

```
["***A***", "Al K. Seltzer", "Alf A. Romeo", "Ali Gaither, Ali Katt", "Amber Green", "***C***", "Cam Payne", "Cara Van", "Craven Moorehead", "Crystal Ball", "Crystal Claire Waters", "***F***", "Ford Parker", "Forrest Green", "Foster Child"]
```